# Is there any way to stream videos using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, video-streaming

hi im trying to create a bot to stream videos in discord voice chat 
but i cant find any docs for video streaming
does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 4):

Bots cannot stream anything other than audio on a voice channel.

Discord's REST - based API all the libraries such as [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/), [Eris](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/getting-started), etc, are based upon does not provide an endpoint for bot applications to stream in voicechannels as of now, although there is a [self-video option in the voice structure](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/voice#voice-state-object-voice-state-structure) it is not available to bots.

[image: Voice Structure]